# Cannot access wp-admin without trailing slash - .htaccess configuration for Wordpress behind a nginx proxy

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, nginx

I have a WordPress instance running via [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware), so I can have my WordPress blog under `example.com/blog`

The problem I'm struggling with is I cannot configure the `.htaccess` file properly.

Here's my config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

By default, WordPress generates all links without the trailing slash.

I can access the following:

`example.com/blog/wp-login.php`

`example.com/blog/wp-admin/`

`example.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php`

But when I go to `example.com/blog/wp-admin` (no trailing slash) the redirection fails.

Same happens when I manually add the trailing slash to a post link:

`example.com/blog/testing` works

`example.com/blog/testing/` fails

I wonder if I should focus on the `http-proxy-middleware` configuration or could it be that my `.htaccess` file is configured incorrectly?

Comment: `/blog/hello-world/wp-admin/` - What's the `/hello-world` part? This is missing from your later URLs. There's nothing in `.htaccess` to handle the trailing slash on WP URLs (nor should there be). All the `.htaccess` code does is route all requests (whether they contain a trailing slash or not) to the WordPress front-controller, ie. `index.php`. WP would then handle the routing. Is the request with a trailing slash reaching WP?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't your proxy? If your WP install is at `/blog/` then you should not be able to access WP Admin at `/blog/hello-world/wp-admin`. Note that we are not a support route for the http-proxy-middleware package

Comment: @MrWhite I'm sorry, my bad - I put the `/hello-world` part by mistake. Of course it should not be there. I updated the origin post. Thanks for the hint though, I'll check if the requests with a trailing slash reaches WP. Then I'll focus on the proxy package, I wanted to make sure the .htaccess configuration is correct before doing so.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with `nginx`? `.htaccess` is an Apache configuration file and has nothing to do with Nginx.

Comment: @RichardSmith It would seem the Apache server is behind an Nginx proxy.

Comment: @RichardSmith The Apache server is behind the nginx proxy and I have considered enforcing the trailing slash at the nginx level. Not sure if this it the way though